# How Insert events into http sink apart from one another?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I need to send events to http endpoint. If I do something like :

```
from DataStream
 select f_id
insert into OutputToHttpEndpoint ;
```

I have following messages in my webservice:

`[{f_id:1}, {f_id:2}, ...]`

instead N request with expected message like `{f_id:N}`.

I found solution:

```
from ExtractedDataStream
 select f_id 
 output last every 1 events 
insert into OutputToNodejs ;
```

Is it's correct? Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: I need a small clarification regarding the requirement. In my understanding [{f_id:1}, {f_id:2}, ...,{f_id:N}] is your input and expected output is {f_id:N}. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct how are you bounding this input. Will it arrive as a batch?

Comment: No. For example - DataStream is select 10 rows from database. I want to send them one by one, not all in one message to http sink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siddhi [length batch window](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/api/latest/#lengthbatch-window) of size 1 can be used,

```
   from DataStream#window.lengthBatch(1)
   select * 
   insert into DataStreamTemp;

   from DataStreamTemp 
   select f_id
   insert into OutputToHttpEndpoint ;
```